# Cannot change span text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the text inside the spans using this piece of jquery but I am unable to. Why does this not work? What is the problem with this piece of code?

```
<html> 
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">< /script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("span").text("Changed");
});
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is a <span>section</span>.</p>

 <p>This is <span>another</span> paragraph.</p>

</body>
 <html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep eyes on console for errors .. In your code you got an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }",`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("span").text("Changed");
});   
}); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<< remove this line
```

Working demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span').text('Changed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a <span>section</span>.</p>
<p>This is <span>another</span> paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("span").text("Changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>This is a <span>section</span></p>

 <p>This is <span>another</span> paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just be more mindful:

1) Space before / in script tag is breaking your code

2) Html should be closed

3) }); is duplicated for some reason

And You can use shorter notation:

```
$(function() {})
```

instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function() { })
```